# Is there an Objective-C library that does the same thing as Ruby-English Gem does?

Tags: objective-c

http://english.rubyforge.org/

require 'english/inflect'

```
    "boy".plural      #=> "boys"
    "ox".plural       #=> "oxen"

    "boys".singular   #=> "boy"
    "oxen".singular   #=> "ox"
```

Comment: I've got one,  https://github.com/RISCfuture/TMInflector but it only handles the inflections

I need a new one to handle english:infinitive

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any provided by Apple and I haven't heard of any third-party libraries that can do that in Objective-C.